# GTAB with access denied to all app databases

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a brand new GTAB (Android)  that was working fine but suddenly, give a reboot while I was using anMonay, a very good application of financial organization.

Until any thing I'd like to observe that I have plenty of space in NAND Flash storage memory, something about 100 MB. This storage is used to keep app's databases under "/data" directory. I'd like to observe that my ROM is original and android version is 2.2.

So after reboot, all applications that effectively uses SQLite stoped to work. Each one gives substantial logs, pointing me that this problem are involving not so exclusive

## App1 ) anMoney

> E/ApplicationContext( 1933): Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp/shared_prefs/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp_preferences.xml to backup file /data/data/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp/shared_prefs/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp_preferences.xml.bak
> E/ApplicationContext( 1933): Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp/shared_prefs/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp_preferences.xml to backup file /data/data/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp/shared_prefs/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp_preferences.xml.bak
>
> I/Database( 1933): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
> E/Database( 1933): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp/databases/My Book", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933): com.zvasvari.anmoneyp.database.az: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at com.zvasvari.anmoneyp.database.sql.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at com.zvasvari.anmoneyp.database.sql.s.a(Unknown Source)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at com.zvasvari.anmoneyp.app.book.a.t.b(Unknown Source)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at com.zvasvari.anmoneyp.app.book.a.t.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1812)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:844)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:540)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
> V/com.zvasvari.anmoneyp( 1933):   ... 10 more

## App 2) Battery Widget

> E/ApplicationContext( 2674): Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.elvison.batterywidget/shared_prefs/com.elvison.batterywidget_preferences.xml to backup file /data/data/com.elvison.batterywidget/shared_prefs/com.elvison.batterywidget_preferences.xml.bak
> E/ApplicationContext( 2674): Couldn't rename file /data/data/com.elvison.batterywidget/shared_prefs/_has_set_default_values.xml to backup file /data/data/com.elvison.batterywidget/shared_prefs/_has_set_default_values.xml.bak
> I/Database( 2674): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
> E/Database( 2674): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.elvison.batterywidget/databases/alarms.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed

To turn things more intriguing, I buied an Andoid app called SQLite Editor and open the 3 individual bases given above. All 3 are intact, without presenting data loss or corruption.

What can be wrong? Any one can point me what is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Try XDA or http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is listed as a bug on the [Android bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14359). It looks like it's fixed on later versions of Android although that probably doesn't help you much.

If it won't cause you too many problems (you said the device is brand new...) you could try a factory reset followed by a reinstall as indicated in the thread. Obviously back up your data first where possible.